# Where does my friend live? 2

Tags: knowledge, geography

<sup>*Other questions in this series can be found [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A71693+%22Where+does+my+friend+live%3F%22+is%3Aq).*</sup>

---

Another of my friends gave me this code to show where he lives:

> RODA, NAYU, GURU, GARA, MOLO, ZENE, LIZA, ANIT, ELIH, IVIL, ANIR

**Can you figure out where he lives?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This time your friend lives in:

> **PERU**

The code consists of:

> 4-letter fragments that can be found *backwards* within the names of 11 of the 12 sovereign states that make up **South America**:
>
>
>  ECU**ADOR**, G**UYAN**A, **URUG**UAY, P**ARAG**UAY, C**OLOM**BIA, V**ENEZ**UELA, BR**AZIL**, ARGEN**TINA**, C**HILE**, BO**LIVI**A, SU**RINA**ME.
>
>  The twelfth country that completes this list is **PERU**, which cannot be included in the coded list without giving away its identity since it is only 4 letters long!

Answer (score 6):

RODA

> Equador

NAYU

> Guyana

GURU

> Uruguay

GARA

> Paraguay

MOLO

> Colombia

ZENE

> Venezuela

LIZA

> Brazil

ANIT

> Argentina

ELIH

> Chile

IVIL

> Bolivia

ANIR

> Suriname

So the missing country is

> Peru

Comment: Snap! What was that - 24 seconds?!

Comment: Don't know, something like that :)

Comment: (+1 by the way - nice spot)

Comment: To be fair, the fastest to answer will be marked. (It makes me so hard since two of you answered at the same time)

Comment: Yes, Stiv was indeed faster and provided a full explanation so np